# How to arrange dissimilar <section> elements to flow inline inside an <article> element

Tags: html, css

I need to create a web site with elements like articles/sections or ul/li to flow inline unless there is no room in the line, at which point the next items would drop below and start a new line of elements.  This is markup:

```
<article style="display:inline; width:900px; height:1000px;">
  <section  class="featured">
    <p>Hello ye wanderers...</p>
    <p>Salutations!</p>
  </section>
  <section  class="featureds">
    <p>A little message here</p>
  </section>
  <section  class="featureds">
    <p>A little message there</p>
  </section>
  <section  class="featureds">
    <p>This is that and so what?</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

And this is the style for the boxes:

```
.featured {
    position:relative;
    width:450px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 2px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.featureds {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #eef;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 2px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
```

And this is the image which shows what I get with this code and what I want to get.
[image: image # 1.]

Now, I know how to do this with position:absolute, but that is not what I want to do.  I need to do this with minimal HTML and CSS wrangling!

If anyone has an idea, I would much appreciate your help

TIA

DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float the sections left:

```
.featureds {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #eef;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 2px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UE9yV/)**

Answer (score 0):

add float:left; to the section .featureds

```
section .featureds{
    float:left;
}
```